# Customizing SERP content for WordPress Blog

Tags: seo, blog

I want to customize the text that appears on the SERP for the posts on my WordPress blog. I want to be able to either provide some custom text or modify the fields that appear on the SERP page, for example, remove Date and shorten the description.

Is there a Plugin available to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Let me start off by saying you can't edit or control what Google displays in its SERPs. They control the format as well as what gets displayed and will determine when they should or should not display a listing a certain way.

Having said that you can do your best to influence what they display.

1) AFAIK you can't have the date removed from the SERPs. Google shows that to show how fresh the content is. If you want the date to be more current then keep the content up to date.

2) To affect the description Google shows in their SERPs you can do the following ([quoting Google](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35264)):

> The **HTML suggestions** page in Webmaster
>   Tools lists pages where Google has
>   detected missing or problematic meta
>   descriptions. (To see this page, click
>   Diagnostics in the left-hand menu of
>   the site Dashboard. Then click HTML
>   suggestions.)
>
> **Differentiate the
>   descriptions for different pages**.
>   Using identical or similar
>   descriptions on every page of a site
>   isn't very helpful when individual
>   pages appear in the web results. In
>   these cases we're less likely to
>   display the boilerplate text. Wherever
>   possible, create descriptions that
>   accurately describe the specific page.
>   Use site-level descriptions on the
>   main home page or other aggregation
>   pages, and use page-level descriptions
>   everywhere else. If you don't have
>   time to create a description for every
>   single page, try to prioritize your
>   content: At the very least, create a
>   description for the critical URLs like
>   your home page and popular pages.
>
> Include clearly tagged facts in the
>   description. The meta description
>   doesn't just have to be in sentence
>   format; it's also a great place to
>   include structured data about the
>   page. For example, news or blog
>   postings can list the author, date of
>   publication, or byline information.
>   This can give potential visitors very
>   relevant information that might not be
>   displayed in the snippet otherwise.
>   Similarly, product pages might have
>   the key bits of information - price,
>   age, manufacturer - scattered
>   throughout a page. A good meta
>   description can bring all this data
>   together. For example, the following
>   meta description provides detailed
>   information about a book.
>
> ```
> <meta name="Description" content="Author: A.N. Author, 
> Illustrator: P. Picture, Category: Books, Price: $17.99, 
> Length: 784 pages">
> ```
>
> In this example,
>   information is clearly tagged and
>   separated.
>
> **Programmatically generate
>   descriptions**. For some sites, like
>   news media sources, generating an
>   accurate and unique description for
>   each page is easy: since each article
>   is hand-written, it takes minimal
>   effort to also add a one-sentence
>   description. For larger
>   database-driven sites, like product
>   aggregators, hand-written descriptions
>   can be impossible. In the latter case,
>   however, programmatic generation of
>   the descriptions can be appropriate
>   and are encouraged. Good descriptions
>   are human-readable and diverse, as we
>   talked about in the first point above.
>   The page-specific data we mentioned in
>   the second point is a good candidate
>   for programmatic generation. Keep in
>   mind that meta descriptions comprised
>   of long strings of keywords don't give
>   users a clear idea of the page's
>   content, and are less likely to be
>   displayed in place of a regular
>   snippet.
>
> **Use quality descriptions**.
>   Finally, make sure your descriptions
>   are truly descriptive. Because the
>   meta descriptions aren't displayed in
>   the pages the user sees, it's easy to
>   let this content slide. But
>   high-quality descriptions can be
>   displayed in Google's search results,
>   and can go a long way to improving the
>   quality and quantity of your search
>   traffic.

3) If your pages contain certain content (reviews, people, businesses, events) you can use [rich snippets](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170) to enhance the appearance of the descriptions in the SERPs.

4) If you want Google to show [breadcrumbs](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/11/new-site-hierarchies-display-in-search.html) for your pages use [microdata](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?&answer=185417).

Comment: In fact, the plugin I linked does include disabling the date in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try Yoast's [Wordpress SEO](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/) plugin. One of the best out there, it lets you pick default titles and descriptions for posts/pages/categories/etc. but also per individual post. It also has a whole lot of other useful SEO options.

It's currently in development still, most of the features already work very fine but you can expect it to be updated a couple of times still.

Alternatively, you could try [Headspace](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/headspace2/) which I used to use before Yoast's plugin was released. Sort of does the same trick but doesn't incorporate the other features Yoast has.

Answer (score 0):

From my not so vast experience, the fastes way of checking the indexed pages and backlinks for an website is by this free tool at http://domof.com which also returns a seo analisys report downloadable as pdf.